# Is there any way to disable the camera beep when I start recording video?

Tags: camera, sony-xperia-arc

I have an Xperia Ray mobile phone and I wanted to get one of those spy camera applications so as to film undetected.

I tried a couple and the best so far were Ninja Cam and Hidden Mobile Camera. However, all of them have one problem: when I turn out the camera there is a beep (regardless if the sound is off or on).

Is there any app that doesn't have this problem? Alternatively, is there any other way I can delete that sound? I don't really need it anyway.

Comment: It may be worth noting that disabling the camera sound can be illegal in some jurisdictions. I know in the US it can vary by state, but this can fall afoul of concealed recording laws since a phone is not considered an obvious recording device in many cases, whereas an actual camera typically needs no sound since it is considered unconcealed. Note that I'm not taking a stance on these laws either way, but if you're uncomfortable with taking that risk then you may want to look up your local laws.

Answer (score 2):

There are several "silent cameras" available on google play, as e.g. [Silent Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=soft.kinoko.SilentCamera) and [Silent Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.marufu.android.toycamera) (and many more) for photos. I remember there was some settings app to completely silence the camera (regardless of the camera app used), but I currently cannot find it.